# ATV need advice on fixing flat tires

Tags: tires, atv, fix-a-flat

I bought a cheap Chinese ATV thats probably 30-40 yrs old, and it runs great and is lots of fun, but shortly after I bought it 2 tires went flat and wont hold air.  I live in MD and theres very few here who will work on it and those who do want like $140 / tire.

The tires that are on it are Carlisle knobby, on the back it says 22 x 11.00-8 and says below replaces 21x12-8.  Front tires are also Carlisle and says 18 x 9.50-8.  I measured the rims and both front and back seem to be 9" diameter.

I know very little about this stuff.  Im wondering, do these have inner tubes that I replace?  Or do I just buy 2 new tires, or replace all 4?  And im seeing when internet searching for same tires they seem to be sold with the rim, but the rims I have arent bad, if I find them without rims cheaper can I change them at home or do I need special tools?

Also any suggestions for what tires to buy?  Im not married to these Carlisles, I just want to be cheap cause I only paid like $250 for this thing.

Comment: If you do replace them look for 4 ply tires, carlisle's are usually 2 ply and suck.

Comment: Thx, any suggestions for what to replace with?

Comment: The "what to buy" part of the question actually makes this off-topic. I'd follow the sizes which are on the tires, as they are most likely to be a direct replacement. Neither tire dimension you give is for a 9" rim, so I'm doubting the rims are 9" ... they both appear to be 8" ... you should be measuring where the bead of the tire sits and not the overall diameter of the rim (exclude the lips).

Comment: And £140 a tire seems reasonable. You'd maybe expect to pay more for a better quality one.

Comment: I guess the main things I want to know are, should I try to fix the existing tires and how to go about that?  If I can find a hole, can I save money by just putting inner tubes inside, or do I need all new tires?  If I replace the tires, I guess I should stick with same sizes that are in there.

Comment: Amazon is where I shop for this type of tire. @Jimmy

Comment: I watched a video about TireJect and decided to give that a try.  Saw other similar products from Slime, etc.  Any advice on using those products instead of replacing tires?